# PureCSS button href link not working

Tags: css, html

I am using purecss to create colored buttons, href is not clickable and working. The button appears fine its just the link that is cause the trouble.

```
<button class='pure-u-1 pure-button pure-button-primary pure-u-md-2-5 button-xlarge' href='#' >Find out more details</button>
```

I am not able to click the button.  Why is this not working?

The button is a large one and looks like this. Please how can i fix this?

[image]

My button CSS is like this:

```
/*
 * -- PURE BUTTON STYLES --
 * I want my pure-button elements to look a little different
 */
.pure-button {
    background-color: #1f8dd6;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

a.pure-button-primary {
    background: white;
    color: #1f8dd6;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 120%;
}

    .button-xsmall {
            font-size: 0.5vw;
        }

        .button-small {
            font-size: 1vw%;
        }

        .button-large {
            font-size: 2vw%;
        }

        .button-xlarge {
            font-size: 2.5vw;
        }

  .button-success,
        .button-error,
        .button-warning,
        .button-secondary {
            color: white;
            border-radius: 4px;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .button-success {
            background: rgb(28, 184, 65); /* this is a green */
        }

        .button-error {
            background: rgb(202, 60, 60); /* this is a maroon */
        }

        .button-warning {
            background: rgb(223, 117, 20); /* this is an orange */
        }

        .button-secondary {
            background: rgb(66, 184, 221); /* this is a light blue */
        }
```

Comment: `href` inside button, put it inside anchor `<a></a>`

Comment: you should <a> and not <button> if you want an href attribute :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKBjKj

Comment: [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: oh! it works :J what a simple solution. I am always thinking about shortcodes. Hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href is just '#', which is a blank placeholder for anchor tags in HTML. The easiest solution is to just wrap your button in an `<a>` tag. For example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <button class='my-class'>Find out more details!</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a href attribute on a button, you would either have to add an onClick="" event or use a simple anchor tag

```css
/*
 * -- PURE BUTTON STYLES --
 * I want my pure-button elements to look a little different
 */
.pure-button {
    background-color: #1f8dd6;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    .button-xsmall {
            font-size: 0.5vw;
        }

        .button-small {
            font-size: 1vw%;
        }

        .button-large {
            font-size: 2vw%;
        }

        .button-xlarge {
            font-size: 2.5vw;
        }

  .button-success,
        .button-error,
        .button-warning,
        .button-secondary {
            color: white;
            border-radius: 4px;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .button-success {
            background: rgb(28, 184, 65); /* this is a green */
        }

        .button-error {
            background: rgb(202, 60, 60); /* this is a maroon */
        }

        .button-warning {
            background: rgb(223, 117, 20); /* this is an orange */
        }

        .button-secondary {
            background: rgb(66, 184, 221); /* this is a light blue */
        }
```

```html
<a class='pure-u-1 pure-button pure-button-primary pure-u-md-2-5 button-xlarge' href='#' >Find out more details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/ysv75326/1/
All I've done is changed the `<button>` into `<input type="button"...` and given it an ID of `test`. Then I set up a `JavaScript` listener for when an element with this ID gets clicked, it runs `alert("Hey");`

Code Snippet:

```js
$("#test").click(function() {
  alert("Hey");
});
```

```css
.pure-button {
  background-color: #1f8dd6;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
a.pure-button-primary {
  background: white;
  color: #1f8dd6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 120%;
}
.button-xsmall {
  font-size: 0.5vw;
}
.button-small {
  font-size: 1vw%;
}
.button-large {
  font-size: 2vw%;
}
.button-xlarge {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
.button-success,
.button-error,
.button-warning,
.button-secondary {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.button-success {
  background: rgb(28, 184, 65);
  /* this is a green */
}
.button-error {
  background: rgb(202, 60, 60);
  /* this is a maroon */
}
.button-warning {
  background: rgb(223, 117, 20);
  /* this is an orange */
}
.button-secondary {
  background: rgb(66, 184, 221);
  /* this is a light blue */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class='pure-u-1 pure-button pure-button-primary pure-u-md-2-5 button-xlarge' href='#' id="test" value="Find out more details">
```